Address Formatting Issue in LaTeX
I'm facing a formatting issue with the address in my LaTeX document. I'm using the following command to specify the address:
\documentclass[manuscript, printscheme]{aomart}
\author{La. La.}
\address{Ministry of National Education Preschool and Sports\\ 
Casablanca, Morocco.}
\orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\end{document}

However, the address spans across lines and displays like this:

I prefer not to force line breaks and avoid indentation in the address. How can I format the address correctly in LaTeX to achieve the following appearance?

How can I achieve this formatting correctly in LaTeX? Is there a proper way to force the line break without compromising the overall document formatting, especially when adhering to the standard style of a scientific journal?

Please provide a MWE with what you try so far. We haven't any information about your document: nor its document class nor page layout.

Set the address inside a tabular with a single, left-aligned column:

\documentclass[manuscript, printscheme]{aomart}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\address{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Ministry of National Education Preschool and Sports \\ 
  Casablanca, Morocco.
\end{tabular}}
\orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\end{document}


I don't think you should. The class is meant for submissions to Annals of Mathematics and their copy editors will take care of the final appearance.
Anyway, you can patch.
\documentclass[
  manuscript,
  printscheme
]{aomart}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\def\\{\unskip, \ignorespaces}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\indent}{\noindent}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\indent}{\noindent}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\indent}{\noindent}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\indent}{\noindent}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\indent}{\noindent}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{Test}
\author{La. La.}
\address{Ministry of National Education Preschool and Sports\\ 
Casablanca, Morocco.}
\orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\end{document}


